# How to get a list of existing files for a user using the Dropbox Javascript API

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

The example of the Dropbox Javascript API makes use of tasks to demonstrate how to use the API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/js).

The example basically creates a tasks table and allows a user to add tasks which become available in a list as existing tasks the next time the user makes use of the app.

What I need to do is access existing files i.e. documents and pictures in a user's Dropbox folder (emphasis on existing). I don't need to allow for a file picker / chooser.

Is the DataStores API able to access existing files, or does it only create and upload new tables to an almost "simulated" data structure? Also, are there additional APIs needed / available to assist with this if the DataStores API is not able to access a user's existing files?

Comment: There's no attempt as far as I can see here.  Is there any code you've attempted?

Comment: Important note: the API you reference is the Datastore API, which is for storing/retrieving data for *your own app*, not for dropbox data.  I think you want the core API, which is available for HTTP but not for javascript directly: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comments. @Pheonixblade9, this is very confusing even to get going with, I worked through the example on the link but couldn't go any further as I was confused by thinking the DataStores API provides actual access to existing files of a user, as Jonathan pointed out...

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing that up @JonathanWilson. It seems that I am confused with the different APIs and so I was not sure to what extent the Datastore API would support what I needed...but you cleared that up. Will definitely have a look at the Core API! Hopefully it works!

Comment: Note that the Datastore JS SDK is a fork of https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js, which includes all the methods you need for working with files.

Comment: Hi @smarx, thanks for your comment. I have started using dropbox-js. It seems that it is able to do what I need. I just need to figure out how to "recursively" find sub-folder contents. For dropbox-js, I would just like to know if it syncs automatically like the Datastore SDK, or do you have to check for changes yourself?

Comment: You need to check for changes yourself. You can use [`pollForChanges`](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#pollForChanges-instance) and [`pullChanges`](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#pullChanges-instance). The first time you call `pullChanges`, you'll get all the files for that user. On subsequent calls, you'll get the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @smarx. If you (or anyone on this thread) are able to assist with a follow-up question, I would appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419338/how-to-use-the-dropbox-js-pullchanges-method-to-get-a-file-list-of-existing-file