# How to use the dropbox-js pullChanges method to get a file list of existing files

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox-js to access a user's dropbox files. Please note that I am very new to this...

What I need to do, is to access existing files using dropbox-js. As I understand it, the `pullChanges` method should be used for this. This is how I currently have it:

```
client.pullChanges(null, function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        return showError(error);
    }

    alert("Dropbox contains: " + results.shouldPullAgain); //just to test that something happens
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to make use of `pullChanges`, and then I need to know how to use `results` to actually get the file/folder information??

Comment: That looks good so far. I think results.entries will have the actual changes. See the [`/delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta) documentation to understand what comes back from this API.

Comment: Hi @smarx, I actually tried `results.entries` and it came up as undefined. So I logged results and it's `results.changes` that shows up all the files - I didn't see anything about changes in the docs? Now I need to put it all back together in a hierarchy, is there any way to do this easily? I basically need the contents of 4 folders that is in a user's dropbox.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. The documentation for the library you're using is here: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#pullChanges-instance, and the results object is of this type: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Http/PulledChanges.html.